# Why does HTTP response body in Postman show more fields than Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to REST APIs and trying to write a program for adding new contacts to a phonebook. I'm using Express and Mongoose / MongoDB. For context, MongoDB automatically creates an ._id and .__v field for each document added to the database.

When I make a POST request to add a new contact from Postman, the response body includes the ._id and .__v fields (see Fig 1). However, when I make a similar POST request from Chrome, the response body doesn't include those two fields (see Fig 2).

Why are they different? Are they not comparable outputs? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something conceptually about how HTTP responses work.

[Fig 1: Fields shown in response body by Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN9lM.png)

[Fig 2: Fields shown in response body by Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5avxm.png)

Comment: You are looking at JSON parsed responses in both tools. Check whether the raw responses are identical first.

Comment: Gotcha, I just clicked on the "Preview" and "Response" tabs and saw that Chrome Dev Tools indeed does have the additional two fields. Is this the same as looking at the raw responses?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why postman show more detailed result id because the Postman app was specifically built for the purpose of outputting full details when intracting with an API.

Comment: So Chrome is receiving the data and filtering it? If so can you point me to docs that explain what data Chrome is not showing?

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3804